# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (38563,54) (38563,) while using curve_fit()

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, curve-fitting, sklearn-pandas

**Note**: This question is not a multiplication one and please ignore some of the import statements.
Now the details are as follows, I am using a curve_fit() to fit a periodic pandas dataset. 
Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

df = pd.read_csv("Metro_Interstate_Traffic_Volume.csv")
df['holiday'].replace(to_replace = 'None', value = '0', inplace=True)
df.loc[df['holiday'] != '0', 'holiday'] = 1
print(df.shape)

df['date_time'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
df['date_time'] = (df['date_time']- dt.datetime(1970,1,1)).dt.total_seconds()

#print(df['date_time'].head())

non_dummy_cols = ['holiday','temp','rain_1h', 'snow_1h', 'clouds_all','date_time', 'traffic_volume'] 

dummy_cols = list(set(df.columns) - set(non_dummy_cols))
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=dummy_cols)
print(df.shape)

x = df[df.columns.values]
x = x.drop(['traffic_volume'], axis=1)
x = x.drop(['clouds_all'], axis = 1)
y = df['traffic_volume']
print(x.shape)
print(y.shape)

#plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
#plt.scatter(df.date_time[0:100], df.traffic_volume[0:100], color = 'blue')
#plt.xlabel("Date Time")
#plt.ylabel("Traffic volume")
#plt.show()

x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size = 0.2, random_state= 4)

def my_sin(x, freq, amplitude, phase, offset):
    return np.sin(x * freq + phase) * amplitude + offset

#x_train = np.array(x_train)
#y_train = np.array(y_train)

print(x_train)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(my_sin, x_train, y_train)
y_hat = my_sin(x_test, *popt)
```

**Error**:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (38563,54) (38563,)
```

**Download** [dataset](https://www.transfernow.net/files/?utm_source=03kof4q1ji0u&utm_medium=&utm_content=en) URL

The dataset before any programmatic changes is:

[image]

So how do i overcome this error? Is it not possible to use curve_fit for a m*n x_train?

I have also tried by reshaping the y_train to m*1 or [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB6P6.png),[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB6P6.png),....[]] like this but that's also not working. So please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: When I run your code, I get a very different error, "FileNotFoundError: File b'Metro_Interstate_Traffic_Volume.csv' does not exist", as if I need the data file to run the code for debugging.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Here you go https://wetransfer.com/downloads/71564b529fbaa34727c7bf43e1046b9220190713170403/314091

Comment: That URL gives a page that requires some kind of legal agreement. My meaning was a link for the data file.

Comment: ok maybe in your area different T&C, please try this https://transfernow.net/03kof4q1ji0u

Answer (score 1):

The entire error message tells the story just above the last line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 50, in <module>
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(my_sin, x_train, y_train)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 736, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 377, in leastsq
    shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 26, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 454, in func_wrapped
    return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (38563,54) (38563,)
```

Curve_fit() is handing your function "my_sin()" data which has shape of (38563, 54) - this is x_train.shape() output - and is *returning* data with the same shape. The curve_fit code needs the function being fitted to instead *return* data with the same shape as y_train, so it can subtract the two and calculate error. Since the function does not return data with the same shape as y_train, the subtraction is giving an exception.

I suspect you should be using the linear regression in sklearn, and not the curve_fit routine.

Comment: I am using curve_fit() because it is a periodic data, linear regression won't fit into it or if you can share the best fitted model to the dataset then it would be really helpful.

Comment: My suggestion is to create a new question, again with a link to the data.

Comment: Question of how to train this model?

Comment: My meaning was a new question on the topic of regressing periodic data with sklearn.

Comment: How will that be helpful?

Comment: I can generate bounty tomorrow, but the views on the question is increasing maybe it is tough to answer

Comment: You ask how that would be helpful; perhaps someone who has solved a similar problem could share their code. Certainly the title to this question might not be read in that way. My thought was that clearly and specifically asking about the problem at hand, rather than about an error message, might be more likely to elicit a useful response.